# Open link in new tab in mobile version of chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

In full site all link open in new tab but in mobile view of chat all link open in same tab and  to see content of  link in new tab We have to press it until new tab menu appears and I can click on *open in new tab*.

So my feature request is open every link in new tab in chat in mobile version too.

Comment: i am really curious to know why  down-voter  is not agree(thinks its useful)  with this  feature request ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The choice to open something in a new tab should almost always be left to the user. The only exceptions are when leaving the current page would cause data loss and the link they are clicking is related but you expect them back (for example help links when filling out forms).

All mobile browsers that I am aware of that support tabs or any form of windows already have a way for the user to open the links in a new tab on their own. For touch screen phones this is usually reached via long-pressing a link, but there are lots of variations on the theme. The user is expected to know the functions of their own phone and browser, every individual site on the web is not responsible for making these decisions on their users behalf.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree. Many phone browsers (some Android ones for example) restrict the number of tabs you can open. If you click a `target=_blank` link, it overwrites one of the older tabs when your tab list is full. This is hard to get around, and in general I find auto-open-in-new-tab links very annoying on mobile.

On the other hand, tap-hold-open-in-new-tab is a quite easy.

Comment: i had never faced like that .. even i opened many tab at a same time .. could you give me official source where it telling that there is tab limit in android since AFAIK there isnt anything like that

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Depends on which Android phone you use -- I mentioned _Some_ in the question. Mine is a Galaxy Mini (on Froyo). Also, iOS Safari has a maximum of 9 tabs.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя I don't have any official sources, but my Galaxy 551 (also on Froyo) has a hard limit of 8 browser tabs.